# Open and display a .txt file on div on user's computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to add a functionality where a user can browse a file and display the content of the file on the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <input id='inpFile' type='file'>
    <button id='submit'>Submit</button>  
    <div id='content'>Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.get($('#inputFile').val(), function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    });
}
```

Nothing is getting updated in the div element and no error is returned.
Please suggest.

UPDATE:

I recently discovered that `$.get()` basically does an http request. But my file is present locally in the system, so is the reason above JS code is not working.

But I can't use HTML5 File or FileReader API as I am working on IE-8, it doesn't support HTML5.

So should I copy the file to the server and then use `$.get()` to get the file contents to div.

Please suggest.

Comment: `get` is for making an HTTP request to a URL, not for reading files from the file system

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/cfd56bhh/1/

Comment: @GregL question is closed so can't answer

Comment: @Moogs — It's a duplicate question. You can answer the duplicate if you think your answer is better then the ones already there.

Comment: @Quentin the duplicates answer the question